# Replace key in a senetence with its value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a dictionary and a list

```
dict1= {'good':'bad','happy':'sad','pro':'anti'}
```

```
list1=['she is good','this is a product','they are pro choice']
```

```
newlist=[]
for index, data in enumerate(list1):
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if key in data:
            list1[index]=data.replace(key, dict1[key])
            newlist.append(list1[index])
```

```
The output I get is
['she is bad','this is a antiduct','they are anti choice']

desired output is
['she is bad','this is a product','they are anti choice']
```

How can I fix it? It is replacing the pro of prodcut too. I only want it to replace pro when it exists as an independent word.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but note that `list1` is a set, not a list.  (`{}` creates either a set or a dict; `[]` is how you create a list.)

Comment: yes, yes. My bad, fixed the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good use case for a regex with word boundaries:

```
dict1 = {'good':'bad','happy':'sad','pro':'anti'}
list1 = ['she is good','this is a product','they are pro choice', 'skimming has a basic dimension - product']

import re

regex = fr'\b({"|".join(map(re.escape, dict1))})\b'
out = [re.sub(regex, lambda m: dict1[m.group()], s) for s in list1]
```

output:

```
['she is bad',
 'this is a product',
 'they are anti choice',
 'skimming has a basic dimension - product']
```

Comment: It is still replacing product with antiduct for some reason

Comment: @Codingamethyst It works with the provided example. Can you provide a counter example?

Comment: 'skimming has a basic dimension - product'

Comment: output- skimming has a identical dimension - antiduct.

Comment: Works fine as well...

Comment: Wonder why it isnt working for my dataset, anyway thanks for the help though(again).

Comment: added basic:incidental to the dict1, now it is changing product to antiduct

Comment: @Codingamethyst I see, there was a missing parenthesis, all fine now!

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to `split` each phrase and do the substitution with a straight `get` on the dictionary, rather than a `replace`:

```
>>> dict1= {'good':'bad','happy':'sad','pro':'anti'}
>>> list1={'she is good','this is a product','they are pro choice'}
>>> [' '.join(dict1.get(word, word) for word in phrase.split()) for phrase in list1]
['this is a product', 'she is bad', 'they are anti choice']
```

Note that this will not preserve whitespace in the phrase, nor will it handle punctuation very well.  `re` and `itertools.groupby` would be useful tools to handle those more complex cases.